# Is 0x Api perform "Dex aggregator" Swaps internally like 1Inch exchange?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, 0x

Is 0x Api performing "Dex aggregator" Swaps internally like 1Inch exchange?

Answer (score 1):

The 0x API is a layer that sits on top of the 0x protocol which you can think of as an “aggregator of aggregators”. This means when you make a swap on 0x, it looks across 3 main sources of liquidity (order books, AMMs, and market makers) to provide you with the best price.

The diagram here -  https://blog.0x.org/exploring-the-0x-defi-ecosystem/ - provides a good visual w/ examples of the different parties.

For more info about how the 0x protocol works, check out the [architecture section](https://protocol.0x.org/en/latest/architecture/overview.html) of the 0x protocol docs.

Lastly, this blog post covers how for a given quote, [0x API's smart routing algorithm](https://blog.0xproject.com/0x-apis-smart-order-routing-7af0195515e5) scans across DEXs for the best prices and will split up the order across the different sources (if relevant) to give the maximum return on a swap.

Hope this helps answer your question.